# Comparing two strings with dot notation not works within Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am comparing two strings which includes dot notation but I am getting always false even the string are the same. 
I have checked the type of the values and also I used trim() and toString() methods but it is not working. What is wrong with my function?

Here is my function:

```
function isInArray(value, array) {
array.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log('########################');
    console.log(entry)
    console.log(value)
    console.log(array)
    console.log(typeof array)
    console.log(typeof entry)
    console.log(typeof value)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(entry) === JSON.stringify(value));
    console.log('#############################');
});
```

**Output:**

```
test.me.please
test.me.please
['test.o.1', 'test.o.2']['test.me.please', 'test.me.again', 'test.me.now']
object
string
string
false
```

```js
function isInArray(value, array) {
  array.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log('########################');
    console.log(entry)
    console.log(value)
    console.log(array)
    console.log(typeof array)
    console.log(typeof entry)
    console.log(typeof value)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(entry) === JSON.stringify(value));
   console.log('#############################');
  });
}
isInArray('test.me.please', ['test.me.please', 'test.me.again', 'test.me.now']);
```

[image]

Comment: What are `value` and `array`?

Comment: entry===value ?

Comment: Inserting your code as a runnable snippet shows it works as expected. Voting to close.

Comment: Actually your code is working. This will output `true` on the first iteration

Comment: Well, if I compare without a variable just the runnable example with 'test.me.please' then it works. but with a variable not. I used toString() method and also set it with quotes

Answer (score 0):

```
function isInArray(value, array) {
    array.forEach(function (entry) {
        console.log(entry === value);
    });
}
```

Your function works fine for me. Make sure your value is actually in the array.

Also, there are already functions you can use to check if a value is in an array:

`Array.includes(value)` returns a `Boolean`.

`Array.indexOf(value)` returns a `Number`. Returns `-1` if the item is not in the array.

Comment: yes, but I have it within a .ts typescript file. Maybe typescript make the problem. It is not working

Answer (score -2):

function isInArray(value, referredValue) {

```
//let isEqual = false;

var isEqual = false;  

if (referredValue.indexOf(value) != -1) {
    isEqual = true;
}
return isEqual;
```

}

Comment: it is the correct way but something is not working for me. really strange. I have my .ts. file for within node.js

Comment: can you share the snapshot of your exact code after using the above function

Comment: Ok done, please check my output as well which I am getting from ldap server. At line 96 I am using includes method and also I tried a loop, iteration, etc.. no way to compare even the value exists in the array